# Adding a button mode to a loaded object/image : ReferenceError: Error #1056

Tags: actionscript-3, button, actionscript, linker-errors, loader

ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property buttonMode on flash.display.Loader.
This was the error when i wrote a code like this

```
load123 = new Loader();
url1 = new URLRequest("abalblal.png");
load123.load(url1);
abc1 = addChild(skill1load);
//btw let's say i declared the variables earlier
abc1.buttonMode = true;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does it say which line the error is on? Usually it does, which should help in finding the cause. The code you've given looks fine, though.

Comment: Yea, sry i forgot to write abc1.buttonMode = true ... xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you don't show this in your code, your title seems to imply that you're trying to do something like this:

```
load123.buttonMode = true;
```

That won't work, however, because the [buttonMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#buttonMode) property is not defined in the [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) class. `buttonMode` is a property of the [Sprite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html) class, and since `Loader` does not inherit from `Sprite` this is just not possible.

You can, however, add your `Loader` to a `Sprite` and then set enable `buttonMode` on that `Sprite`:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.addChild(loader123);
s.buttonMode = true;
```

Comment: Oh i see... thanks man I was thinkin of that method but anyway thx :)

Comment: This was helpful thanks. However if I add to the Sprite container a name like this `s.name ="container1"` and if in my function of the addEventListener I try to trace the name, I don't know how to do it: `trace(this.name)` returns `instance56` I'd like to be able to get the name I set earlier. Any ideas? Thanks